# Swift SpriteKit can't recursively call function with SKAction

Tags: recursion, sprite-kit, swift4

```
func Game(){
     var actionwait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3)
     var actionrun = SKAction.run({
          var randomIndex1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.button.count)))
          var randomItem1 = self.button[randomIndex1]
          self.poupButtonImage.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: self.images[randomIndex1])
          self.popupButtonImage.zPosition += 1
          self.continuationSequence.text?.append(randomItem1)
          self.winner.zPosition += 1
          self.winner.text = (randomItem1)
    })

    if(self.winner.text == self.buttonPressed.text){
        print ("Chicken Dinner")
        winner.run(SKAction.sequence([actionwait,actionrun]))
        Game()
    }
    else{
        print ("You lost")

    }

}
```

> When the Game() function is called in the if block it just keeps printing chicken dinner and the variables in the action run portion of code are never generated after the initial run. I used the debugger but couldn't not figure out the reason for the behavior.

Comment: Calling recursively such a code is non-sense. What do you want to do? If you want to repeat an action, just use `SKAction.repeat`

Comment: First, your function as written is going to recurse itself into a crash. Second, when you call `winner.run` your app isn't going sit there and wait for the sequence to finish. The sequence is scheduled to run *later*, on a different execution thread, while your app runs full steam ahead. So you're calling `Game()` recursively in a hard loop. If you really do want `Game()` to run again *after* the sequence is complete, then add a `run(_:completion:)` to the end of your sequence and have it call `Game()`. I believe that will fix your recursion problem too.

Comment: @GreatBigBore Thank you so much!! I literally spent hours trying to figure the problem!!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! You've made my day. Peace and luck to you.